# C program prepends, when it should append

Tags: c, append, prepend

Trying to write a program in C, which I've never used before, to convert hexadecimal to binary as a string and write it to a file, The only problem is that it prepends to the output file when I want it to append.
This occurs for both fprintf() and fputs().

This is the append code:

```
while(fgets(line,1024,inputFile)){
  lineLen = strlen(line);
  binary = hexToBin(line, lineLen);
  printf("Binary: %s\n", binary);

  // output file does not exist
  FILE *writeFile = fopen(argv[2], "a");
  if (writeFile == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "write file not found: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("appending binary to file\n");
  fprintf(writeFile,"%s\n",binary);
  printf("appended\n");
}
```

This is the hexToBin function:

```
char* hexToBin(char hex[], size_t len){
  // convert hexadecimal to binary
  char *binString = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*4*len);
  for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
      char *binNum = hexToBinHelp(hex[i]);
      strcat(binString,binNum);
      free(binNum);
  }
  return binString;
}
```

hexToBinHelp returns the hexadecimal character as a char* of it's binary representation (binNum=[0][0][0][0] for example). It's really long so I'd rather not put it here, but can if it would help.

When input file is:

```
000a
a000
```

Output file is:

```
1010000000000000
0000000000001010
```

Thanks

Comment: Note that `malloc()` doesn't initialize the data it returns.  Either use `calloc()`, which does zero the bytes of data, or set `binString[0] = '\0';` before concatenating.

Comment: Funny, `hexToBinHelp()` should be quite short; the easiest implementation calls another (also small) function to convert an ASCII hex digit to a value 0..15 (call it `hexdigit()`), and then you can use: `const char *hexToBinHelp(char hex) { int hexval = hexdigit(hex); assert(hexval >= 0 && hexval < 16); static const char *bitstring[] = { "0000", "0001", "0010", …, "1101", "1110", "1111" }; return bitstring[hexval]; }` — you probably need a less assertive error handling mechanism.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Did the first bit. Yeah, it probably could be shorter but it's basically just a massive wall of if-statements that worked so I could try to figure out the append thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop is calling fopen() every iteration, and never closing or flushing this file stream. Writes are buffered, waiting for the buffer to fill or be flushed or the file to be closed; so the next time you call fopen() you get the same pointer as the first time.

You're lucky it's not crashing. :) Do not call fopen() repeatedly. Call it once outside the loop, inside use or move the pointer over, and back outside call fclose().

Comment: Thank you. Took a bit, but I got it working.  I added the fclose(writeFile) right after the fprintf line. I also had to move  the free(binary) line to after that as well (for anyone curious) and that seems to have done it.

Comment: You're welcome. Opening and closing the same file every iteration of the loop will work, but is unnecessary; it would be better, for performance and in general, to keep it open from outside, just like you do with the inputFile pointer. fprintf() moves the writeFile pointer automatically every time, so it keeps track by itself where to write next. Use the buffer Luke, ;) it's made to be your friend not your enemy.